# How to combine two re.compile regex in python3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pydev

I want to combine two regex's into one line.

```
 soup1=link.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('^http://')})
 soup2=link.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/news/")})
```

I tried `(|)` sign in a way `re.compile('^http://' | '/news/')` but all in vain. I need both functionalities (Links containing `'http'` as well as `/news/`)

Comment: No! I want AND condition. not OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question:

> I want to combine two regex's into one line... I need both functionalities (Links containing `'http'` as well as `/news/`)

I understand **as well as** as a requirement for both `http` and `/news/` to be present in the string. Thus, you may use a simple

```
re.compile(r'^http://.*/news/')
```

It will match `http` at the start and `/news/` substring somewhere inside the string.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` -  start of string
- `http://` - a sequence of literal characters
- `.*` - 0+ any characters but a newline
- `/news/` - substring `/news/`.

**Alternation to get results with *either* `http` at the start *or* `/news/` inside**

The `|` alternation operator is used *inside the regex pattern*, not in between regex patterns inside `re.compile`:

```
re.compile(r'^http://|/news/')
                     ^
```

Here, `^` only belongs to `http` (the first branch). `^http://` matches `http://` at the string start -OR- the `/news`  branch matches `/news/` anywhere inside the string. So, all values will be matched that have *either* `http` at the beginning, or `/news/` inside the string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex, you can use *css selectors:*

```
 soup.select('a[href^=http://],a[href*=/news/]')
```

`^=` looks for hrefs staring with the substring, `*=` look for hrefs that contain the substring anywhere.

Comment: Can you combine the selectors in one `select`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, you can comma separate.

Comment: But does it mean `AND` or `OR`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. it gets both.

Comment: So, it does not meet the requirement *Links containing `http` as well as `/news/`* - if it is meant that there must be both. The question is unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I don't read the question that way. I think they just don't want two find_all's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`re.compile(r'(^http://)|(/news/)')`

What you tried is almost correct, `re.compile('^http://' | '/news/')`, just put them inside single quotes as: `re.compile('^http://|/news/')`.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
nombre = soup.findAll('a',{'href':re.compile('^http |'+'.'+palabra+'.',flags=re.IGNORECASE)})
```